# How to check what is queued in ActiveJob using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activejob

I'm working on a reset_password method in a Rails API app. When this endpoint is hit, an ActiveJob is queued that will fire off a request to Mandrill (our transactional email client). I'm currently trying to write the tests to ensure that that the ActiveJob is queued correctly when the controller endpoint is hit.

```
def reset_password
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
  @user.send_reset_password_instructions
end
```

The send_reset_password_instructions creates some url's etc before creating the ActiveJob which's code is below:

```
class SendEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new
    mandrill.messages.send_template "reset-password", [], message
  rescue Mandrill::Error => e
    puts "A mandrill error occurred: #{e.class} - #{e.message}"
    raise
  end
end
```

At the moment we are not using any adapters for the ActiveJob, so I just want to check with Rspec that the ActiveJob is queued.

Currently my test looks something like this (I'm using factory girl to create the user):

```
require 'active_job/test_helper'

describe '#reset_password' do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  it 'should create an ActiveJob to send the reset password email' do
    expect(enqueued_jobs.size).to eq 0
    post :reset_password, user: { email: user.email }
    expect(enqueued_jobs.size).to eq 1
  end
end
```

Everything works in reality, I just need to create the tests!

I'm using ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.6.

I can't see any documentation or help anywhere on the web on how to test on this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The accepted answer no longer works for me, so I tried Michael H.'s suggestion in the comments, which works.

```
describe 'whatever' do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  after do
    clear_enqueued_jobs
  end  

  it 'should email' do
    expect(enqueued_jobs.size).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. Is there any way to check that the correct job is queued?

Comment: The `ActiveJob::TestHelper` ist intended to be used with minitest not rspec. It's code is full of `assert_equal` etc. Including it only for one method is bad idea, imho. The method `enqueued_jobs` within this module is just a shortcut for `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs`

Comment: @bobomoreno `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs` will give you access to the particular jobs that have been queued.

Comment: You can also do `expect { your_action }.to change(enqueued_jobs, :size).by n`, I like to use this to test that no job has been enqueued, using n = 0. You don't even have to do the clear_enqueued_jobs after suite using this method.

Answer (score 49):

In a unit test, instead of checking what is queued one can also rely on ActiveJob working properly and just verify that it will be called by mocking its api.

```
 expect(MyJob).to receive(:perform_later).once 
 post :reset_password, user: { email: user.email }
```

The creators of the ActiveJob have used the same techniques for their unit tests. See [GridJob Testobject](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/test/jobs/gid_job.rb)

They create a testmock GridJob in their tests and override the perform method, so that it only adds jobs to a custom Array, they call [JobBuffer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/test/support/job_buffer.rb). At the end they test, whether the buffer has jobs enqueued

At a single place one can ofc also do an integrations test. The ActiveJob [test_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb) is supposed to be used with minitest not with rspec. So you have to rebuild it's functionalitity. You can just call

```
expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs).to eq 1
```

without requiring anything

**Update 1:**
As noticed within a comment.
`ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs` works only by setting it the queue_adapter into test mode.

```ruby
# either within config/environment/test.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test

# or within a test setup
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
```

Comment: So I ended up doing your first suggestion. The ActiveJob test_helper doesn't work with rspec annoyingly

Comment: @mylescc I was able to get the test_helper working by including it in my Rspec.describe block: `include ActiveJob::TestHelper`

Comment: not sure still didn't work for me. I have tried including inside describe and also tried in configure block as well.

Comment: ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs doesn't work anymore =(

Comment: Testing against `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs` works as long as `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test` is in your config/environments/test.rb file.

Comment: `expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs).to eq 1`
should be
`expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.size).to eq 1`,
missing `.size`.

Comment: The example spec you used won't actually work. The expectation needs to appear before the method that propagates the call.

Answer (score 21):

[Rspec 3.4](http://rspec.info/blog/2015/11/rspec-3-4-has-been-released/) now has [have_enqueued_job](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher) cooked in, which makes this a lot easier to test:

```
it "enqueues a YourJob" do
  expect {
    get :your_action, {}
  }.to have_enqueued_job(YourJob)
end
```

it has other niceties for `have_enqueued_job` to allow you to check the argument(s) and the number of times it should be queued up.

Comment: Whoever find this useful, I've used `expect { }.to have_enqueued_job.on_queue('mailers')` to check sent emails.

Comment: Excellent recommendation!

Answer (score 12):

[Testing Rails ActiveJob with RSpec](https://medium.com/@chuckjhardy/testing-rails-activejob-with-rspec-5c3de1a64b66)

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :urgent

  rescue_from(NoResultsError) do
    retry_job wait: 5.minutes, queue: :default
  end

  def perform(*args)
    MyService.call(*args)
  end
end

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyJob, type: :job do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  subject(:job) { described_class.perform_later(123) }

  it 'queues the job' do
    expect { job }
      .to change(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs, :size).by(1)
  end

  it 'is in urgent queue' do
    expect(MyJob.new.queue_name).to eq('urgent')
  end

  it 'executes perform' do
    expect(MyService).to receive(:call).with(123)
    perform_enqueued_jobs { job }
  end

  it 'handles no results error' do
    allow(MyService).to receive(:call).and_raise(NoResultsError)

    perform_enqueued_jobs do
      expect_any_instance_of(MyJob)
        .to receive(:retry_job).with(wait: 10.minutes, queue: :default)

      job
    end
  end

  after do
    clear_enqueued_jobs
    clear_performed_jobs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

There is a new [rspec extension](https://github.com/gocardless/rspec-activejob) which makes your life easier.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyController do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:params) { { user_id: user.id } }
  subject(:make_request) { described_class.make_request(params) }

  it { expect { make_request }.to enqueue_a(RequestMaker).with(global_id(user)) }
end
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, ensure a job was enqueued when a request is performed is important.
You can do it with the below solutions:

## Solution 1

```
expect{ post your_api_here, params: params, headers: headers }
 .to have_enqueued_job(YourJob)
 .with(args)
```

## Solution 2

```
expect(YourJob).to receive(:perform_later).once.with(args)
post your_api_here, params: params, headers: headers
```

Answer (score 5):

I had some problems, maybe because I didn't include ActiveJob::TestHelper, but this worked for me...

Firstly ensure, that you have the queue adapter set to `:test` as above answers show.

For some reason `clear_enqueued_jobs` jobs in the `after` block didn't work for me, but the [source](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveJob/TestHelper/clear_enqueued_jobs) shows we can do the following: `enqueued_jobs.clear`

```
require 'rails_helper'
include RSpec::Rails::Matchers

RSpec.describe "my_rake_task", type: :rake do

  after do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.clear
  end  


  context "when #all task is run" do
    it "enqueues jobs which have been enabled" do
      enabled_count = get_enabled_count
      subject.execute
      expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.size).to eq(enabled_count)
    end

    it "doesn't enqueues jobs which have been disabled" do
      enabled_count = get_enabled_count
      subject.execute
      expect(ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs.size).to eq(enabled_count)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solutions using `expect { your_code }.to have_enqueued_job(YourJob)` to be very clean, since they use the "official" assertions. If you do not like long blocks passed to `expect`, you can also use:

```rb
YourJob.perform_later
expect(YourJob).to have_been_enqueued
```

Please find good examples in the [rubydoc documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FMatchers%3Ahave_enqueued_job).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # Automatically retry jobs that encountered a deadlock
  # retry_on ActiveRecord::Deadlocked

  # Most jobs are safe to ignore if the underlying records are no longer available
  # discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError
  #

  def self.my_jobs
    enqueued_jobs.select{|x| x['job_class'] == self.name}
  end
end
```

then you can use helper method `my_jobs` in test like

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SendBookingRemindersJob, type: :job do
  describe '.start_time_approaching' do
      let!(:booking) { create :booking } 

      it 'schedules 4 jobs' do
        SendBookingRemindersJob.start_time_approaching(booking)
        expect(SendBookingRemindersJob.my_jobs.count).to eq(4)
      end
  end
```