# Testing Mails queued with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, testing, rspec, sidekiq

Because we need to have the ability to schedule email delivery, we have migrated to using Sidekiq to send emails with the `deliver_later` method.  Under the old regime that used `deliver_now`, our testing could use

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[index]
```

to inspect the recipient, subject, body, attachments, etc...

For testing purposes, is there an equivalent mechanism to inspect the contents of queued email when using Sidekiq and `deliver_later`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test ActionMailer deliver\_later with rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27647749/895789)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for me this was more complex than simply wrapping the code block in a TestHelper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to execute `perform_enqueued_jobs` after all emails were queued.  After this, all of the existing testing mechanisms worked.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

For testing contents of the email, you have to render the email template for which the job needs to be executed. I suggest you should separate unit tests:

1. Job spec to check if email is getting enqueued with correct parameters.
2. Email spec to check the email contents.

If you want to go the end-to-end style, use `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` to execute the job and then use `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[index]` like before.